# Visual Studio 2022 VUE3 Project Won't Start "Unable to start debugging"

Tags: vuejs3, visual-studio-2022

Background: I have a VUE3 WebApp created using the VS2022 templates
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-create-vue-app?view=vs-2022
that was working well on a desktop (Windows 10 Pro) and a laptop (Windows 11 Home); i.e. I could open Visual Studio 2022; have the WebApp as the start-up project; click run/debug and it would run up.

Current Issue: On the desktop this continues to work as expected; however on the laptop when I go to startup the WebApp I get a message "Unable to start debugging. The startup project cannot be launched. Ensure that the correct project is set as the startup project. .... Additionally make sure its debug settins are correctly configured in project properties"

Project Properties: the two machines have the same project properties; nothing really in there other than Startup Command is npm run serve

I don't believe I've changed anything and the two machines are using the same source control repository and branch; just wondering how I work around this / what might have changed. I've done Visual Studio 2022 Updates on both machines (so up to current version on both machines). One difference is on the WebApp project if I right click, select Debug, on the laptop the options are all greyed-out; on the desktop you can select "Start new instance", "Start new instance with debugging", etc..

Any ideas on what is happening here? Or troubleshooting steps I can take to resolve?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the exact same issue recently. Below are what fixed it for me.

I found out my git repo was ignoring the webapi/Properties/launchSettings.json file so it wasn't commited and pulled down onto my secondary work environment.

The launchSettings.json configures the environment for local development environment of the webapi server. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#lsj

As a follow-up, you would have likely missed the vueapp/.vscode/launch.json too. In my repo, this file was also ignored due to my .gitignore.

The launch.json file configures the varies endpoints (e.g. swagger, http, https) and environment variables. Despite the link doco above describing that this is used by VSCode only. Visual Studio's "Deploy" step relies on the existence of this file.

Manually force stage and commit the launch.json file. Otherwise Visual Studio will fail the "deploy" step with a "Error reading JToken from JsonReader path..." error in the Build log as it fails to find the launch.json file.

Comment: Had a similar issue with running Angular with .Net 6, and issue happened due to missing `/.vscode/l` folder, which contains a `launch.json` to launch the JS app.